# How can I check whether a word is reserved by PHP?

Tags: php, reserved-words

Is there some function for checking whether a word is [reserved](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) in PHP or I can use it myself? I can check it manually: just use it and see the error or warning, but I need to automate this check. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The first user comment on that page already has them in array form, so …

Comment: There is no way to check for reserved word usage *within* the executing PHP code, so this would only be useful to try and "analyze" text content (which requires a proper parser to do correctly) -- Just write valid code (which is harder than simply avoiding keywords) and use a smart editor which allows differentiating the color of such reserved words.

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in function for this. You would have to create your own (or use a third-party function/library), maybe putting all words that are reserved in php (keywords/functions etc...) in a file and try to find them programmatically in your files.

Comment: I agree that it's a good idea that you just create an array with all the possible reserved words and check if your word is there.

Comment: How do you want to use that function? In which context? To do what?

Comment: Why would you do this? Are you trying to sanitise `eval` arguments using blacklisting? Just, um, don't even go near this...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit didn't see that sorry

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, I want sanitise `eval` arguments using blacklist

Comment: @Victor: Called it. Simply, do not. Ever! You will get it wrong, and your system will be compromised.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit but if I good sanitise this code, it will be work stable

Comment: @Victor: No, you will make a mistake. This approach is _highly_ dangerous and almost guaranteed to be imperfect. Pick a better approach.

Comment: @Victor: LRIO is correct. If you ABSOLUTELY MUST, MUST use Eval then please restrict access as much as possible (preferably keep out of the same internet as the rest of us) and use a whitelist, not a blacklist.

Comment: @symcbean I thought about `whitelist` too, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array borrowed from http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php

You could easily modify it to work for the predefined constants array.

*This works.*

```
<?php
$keywords = array('__halt_compiler', 'abstract', 'and', 'array', 'as', 'break', 'callable', 'case', 'catch', 'class', 'clone', 'const', 'continue', 'declare', 'default', 'die', 'do', 'echo', 'else', 'elseif', 'empty', 'enddeclare', 'endfor', 'endforeach', 'endif', 'endswitch', 'endwhile', 'eval', 'exit', 'extends', 'final', 'for', 'foreach', 'function', 'global', 'goto', 'if', 'implements', 'include', 'include_once', 'instanceof', 'insteadof', 'interface', 'isset', 'list', 'namespace', 'new', 'or', 'print', 'private', 'protected', 'public', 'require', 'require_once', 'return', 'static', 'switch', 'throw', 'trait', 'try', 'unset', 'use', 'var', 'while', 'xor');

$predefined_constants = array('__CLASS__', '__DIR__', '__FILE__', '__FUNCTION__', '__LINE__', '__METHOD__', '__NAMESPACE__', '__TRAIT__');

$checkWord='break'; // <- the word to check for.
if (in_array($checkWord, $keywords)) {
    echo "Found.";
}

else {
echo "Not found.";
}

?>
```

---

You could also implement this in conjunction with a form by replacing:

```
$checkWord='break';
```

with

```
$checkWord=$_POST['checkWord'];
```

I.e.:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$keywords = array('__halt_compiler', 'abstract', 'and', 'array', 'as', 'break', 'callable', 'case', 'catch', 'class', 'clone', 'const', 'continue', 'declare', 'default', 'die', 'do', 'echo', 'else', 'elseif', 'empty', 'enddeclare', 'endfor', 'endforeach', 'endif', 'endswitch', 'endwhile', 'eval', 'exit', 'extends', 'final', 'for', 'foreach', 'function', 'global', 'goto', 'if', 'implements', 'include', 'include_once', 'instanceof', 'insteadof', 'interface', 'isset', 'list', 'namespace', 'new', 'or', 'print', 'private', 'protected', 'public', 'require', 'require_once', 'return', 'static', 'switch', 'throw', 'trait', 'try', 'unset', 'use', 'var', 'while', 'xor');

$predefined_constants = array('__CLASS__', '__DIR__', '__FILE__', '__FUNCTION__', '__LINE__', '__METHOD__', '__NAMESPACE__', '__TRAIT__');
$checkWord=$_POST['checkWord'];

if (in_array($checkWord, $keywords)) {
    echo "FOUND!!";
}

else {
echo "Not found.";
   }

}

?>

<form method="post" action="">

Enter word to check: 
<input type="text" name="checkWord">

<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Check for reserved word">
</form>
```

---

A different version using both arrays set inside a form.

It could stand for some polishing up, but it does the trick

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$keywords = array('__halt_compiler', 'abstract', 'and', 'array', 'as', 'break', 'callable', 'case', 'catch', 'class', 'clone', 'const', 'continue', 'declare', 'default', 'die', 'do', 'echo', 'else', 'elseif', 'empty', 'enddeclare', 'endfor', 'endforeach', 'endif', 'endswitch', 'endwhile', 'eval', 'exit', 'extends', 'final', 'for', 'foreach', 'function', 'global', 'goto', 'if', 'implements', 'include', 'include_once', 'instanceof', 'insteadof', 'interface', 'isset', 'list', 'namespace', 'new', 'or', 'print', 'private', 'protected', 'public', 'require', 'require_once', 'return', 'static', 'switch', 'throw', 'trait', 'try', 'unset', 'use', 'var', 'while', 'xor');

$predefined_constants = array('__CLASS__', '__DIR__', '__FILE__', '__FUNCTION__', '__LINE__', '__METHOD__', '__NAMESPACE__', '__TRAIT__');

$checkWord=$_POST['checkWord'];

$checkconstant=$_POST['checkconstant'];

if (in_array($checkWord, $keywords)) {
    echo "<b>Reserved word FOUND!!</b>";
    echo "\n";
}

else {
echo "Reserved word not found or none entered.";
   }

if (in_array($checkconstant, $predefined_constants)) {
    echo "<b>Constant word FOUND!!</b>";
    echo "\n";
}

else {
echo "Constant not found or none entered.";
   }

}

?>

<form method="post" action="">

Enter reserved word to check: 
<input type="text" name="checkWord">

Enter constant word to check: 
<input type="text" name="checkconstant">

<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Check for reserved words">
<input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset">
</form>
```

Comment: should be noted you might also want to check `"true"` `"false"` `"null"` depending on your usage

Comment: this is not a complete list of reserved words. you does not include self and parent.

Answer (score 2):

you can build your own automated function.
To do that use an array that hold all the reserved word.[Check out for more information](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php)

Comment: This answer doesn't provide any examples or explanation of the function you're describing, and the link to PHP keywords isn't an exhaustive list of reserved words.

Answer (score 2):

`in_array()` is a bad solution, [as this iterates over every single element within the array, taking `O(n)` time,](https://ideone.com/j44qGt) whereas using a lookup hash can be done in `O(1)` time.

To be clear, the solution below uses [the four lists on php.net:][2]

- List of Keywords — 71 Keywords
- Predefined Classes — 18 Keywords
- Predefined Constants — 57 Keywords
- List of other reserved words &mdash 13 Keywords

[**Full Working Demo Online**](https://ideone.com/j44qGt)

```
    class PHPReservedWords {
        public function isWordReserved($args) {
            $word = $args['word'];
            
            if($this->GetPHPReservedWordsHash()[$word]) {
                return TRUE;
            }
            
            return FALSE;
        }
        
        public function GetPHPReservedWordsHash() {
            if($this->word_hash) {
                return $this->word_hash;
            }
            
            $hash = [];
            
            foreach($this->GetPHPReservedWords() as $word) {
                $hash[$word] = TRUE;
            }
            
            return $this->word_hash = $hash;
        }
        public function GetPHPReservedWords() {
            return [
                        # Primary Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.php
                        # ----------------------------------------------------------
                        
                    # List 1 of 4: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php
                    # ----------------------------------------------------------------
            
                '__halt_compiler',
                'abstract',
                'and',
                'array',
                'as',
                'break',
                'callable',
                'case',
                'catch',
                'class',
                'clone',
                'const',
                'continue',
                'declare',
                'default',
                'die',
                'do',
                'echo',
                'else',
                'elseif',
                'empty',
                'enddeclare',
                'endfor',
                'endforeach',
                'endif',
                'endswitch',
                'endwhile',
                'eval',
                'exit',
                'extends',
                'final',
                'finally',
                'fn',           # (as of PHP 7.4)
                'for',
                'foreach',
                'function',
                'global',
                'goto',
                'if',
                'implements',
                'include',
                'include_once',
                'instanceof',
                'insteadof',
                'interface',
                'isset',
                'list',
                'match',        # (as of PHP 8.0)
                'namespace',
                'new',
                'or',
                'print',
                'private',
                'protected',
                'public',
                'readonly',     # (as of PHP 8.1.0)
                'require',
                'require_once',
                'return',
                'static',
                'switch',
                'throw',
                'trait',
                'try',
                'unset()',
                'use',
                'var',
                'while',
                'xor',
                'yield',
                'yield from',
                        
                    # List 2 of 4: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php
                    # ---------------------------------------------------------------
                
                'Directory',
                'stdClass',
                '__PHP_Incomplete_Class',
                'Exception',
                'ErrorException',
                'php_user_filter',
                'Closure',
                'Generator',
                'ArithmeticError',
                'AssertionError',
                'DivisionByZeroError',
                'Error',
                'Throwable',
                'ParseError',
                'TypeError',
                'self',
                'static',
                'parent',
                        
                    # List 3 of 4: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php
                    # ---------------------------------------------------------------
                    
                'PHP_VERSION',
                'PHP_MAJOR_VERSION',
                'PHP_MINOR_VERSION',
                'PHP_RELEASE_VERSION',
                'PHP_VERSION_ID',
                'PHP_EXTRA_VERSION',
                'PHP_ZTS',
                'PHP_DEBUG',
                'PHP_MAXPATHLEN',
                'PHP_OS',
                'PHP_OS_FAMILY',
                'PHP_SAPI',
                'PHP_EOL',
                'PHP_INT_MAX',
                'PHP_INT_MIN',
                'PHP_INT_SIZE',
                'PHP_FLOAT_DIG',
                'PHP_FLOAT_EPSILON',
                'PHP_FLOAT_MIN',
                'PHP_FLOAT_MAX',
                'DEFAULT_INCLUDE_PATH',
                'PEAR_INSTALL_DIR',
                'PEAR_EXTENSION_DIR',
                'PHP_EXTENSION_DIR',
                'PHP_PREFIX',
                'PHP_BINDIR',
                'PHP_BINARY',
                'PHP_MANDIR',
                'PHP_LIBDIR',
                'PHP_DATADIR',
                'PHP_SYSCONFDIR',
                'PHP_LOCALSTATEDIR',
                'PHP_CONFIG_FILE_PATH',
                'PHP_CONFIG_FILE_SCAN_DIR',
                'PHP_SHLIB_SUFFIX',
                'PHP_FD_SETSIZE',
                'E_ERROR',
                'E_WARNING',
                'E_PARSE',
                'E_NOTICE',
                'E_CORE_ERROR',
                'E_CORE_WARNING',
                'E_COMPILE_ERROR',
                'E_COMPILE_WARNING',
                'E_USER_ERROR',
                'E_USER_WARNING',
                'E_USER_NOTICE',
                'E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR',
                'E_DEPRECATED',
                'E_USER_DEPRECATED',
                'E_ALL',
                'E_STRICT',
                'true',
                'false',
                'null',
                'PHP_WINDOWS_EVENT_CTRL_C',
                'PHP_WINDOWS_EVENT_CTRL_BREAK',
                        
                    # List 4 of 4: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.other-reserved-words.php
                    # ---------------------------------------------------------------
                    
                'int',
                'float',
                'bool',
                'string',
                'true',
                'false',
                'null',
                'void',         # (as of PHP 7.1)
                'iterable',     # (as of PHP 7.1)
                'object',       # (as of PHP 7.2)
                'resource',
                'mixed',
                'numeric',
            ];
        }
    }
    
    $reserved_words = new PHPReservedWords();
    print($reserved_words->isWordReserved(['word'=>'new']));
```

Comment: Undefined array key "maxlength" in GetPHPReservedWordsHash()

Comment: i like this idea for the sake of efficient lookup, but the hash is built inefficiently - `array_flip()` would be much better. The idea is to switch the values into keys, so the values OF those keys don't matter. And to address the "maxlength" comment, coalesce the array accessor to `false` or use `isset()`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. As you mentioned in link, we have a list of this names, so why just check in this way?:

```
   $keywords = array('__halt_compiler', 'abstract', 'and', 'array', 'as', 'break', 'callable', 'case', 'catch', 'class', 'clone', 'const', 'continue', 'declare', 'default', 'die', 'do', 'echo', 'else', 'elseif', 'empty', 'enddeclare', 'endfor', 'endforeach', 'endif', 'endswitch', 'endwhile', 'eval', 'exit', 'extends', 'final', 'for', 'foreach', 'function', 'global', 'goto', 'if', 'implements', 'include', 'include_once', 'instanceof', 'insteadof', 'interface', 'isset', 'list', 'namespace', 'new', 'or', 'print', 'private', 'protected', 'public', 'require', 'require_once', 'return', 'static', 'switch', 'throw', 'trait', 'try', 'unset', 'use', 'var', 'while', 'xor');

 var_dump(in_array('__halt_compiler',$keywords));
```

Comment: There is no build-in function for it? I need to use array of keywords by myself?

Comment: I also was trying to find som etima ago, but without result. So you can write a custom function for checking

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this function `isRW(string $string) NULL|false|string` try it.. it will return `NULL` if the input is not a word, and will return a boolean `false` if the input is not reserved, and a `string` *(PHP lexical token name)* if the input is reserved..

```
function isRW($str){
    if(!preg_match("/^\w{1,20}/", $str)) return null; $rsv=false;
    $uc  = ['true','false','parent','self']; //uncheckable list
    $tk  = token_get_all('<?php '.(boolval($str)? $str:'x')); $tknm=token_name($tk[1][0]); 
    $cst = get_defined_constants(true); unset($cst['user']); global $phpcst; 
    $phpcst = !isset($phpcst)? array_merge(...array_column($cst, null)): $phpcst;

    if($tknm!='T_STRING'
    or in_array($str, $uc)  //if it's uncheckable 
    or @settype($str, $str) //if it's a type like int,NULL,object..
    or preg_match("/__\w/", $str) //PHP reserved all methods prefixed by "__" for future use
    or array_key_exists($str, $phpcst) //if it's a PHP const
    or (function_exists($str) and (new \ReflectionFunction($str))->isInternal())
    or (class_exists($str)    and (new \ReflectionClass($str))->isInternal())) $rsv=true;

    return $rsv? $tknm: $rsv;
}
```

some test outputs :

```
isRW('}');                  //return null
isRW('foobar');             //return boolean false
isRW('void');               //return boolean false
isRW('isInternal');         //return boolean false
isRW('_call');              //return boolean false
isRW('__call');             //return string T_STRING
isRW('__halt_compiler');    //return string T_HALT_COMPILER
isRW('private');            //return string T_PRIVATE
isRW('__DIR__');            //return string T_DIR
isRW('global');             //return string T_GLOBAL
isRW('E_ERROR');            //return string T_STRING
isRW('DATE_ISO8601');       //return string T_STRING
isRW('PHP_SAPI');           //return string T_STRING
isRW('namespace');          //return string T_NAMESPACE
isRW('function');           //return string T_FUNCTION
isRW('ReflectionClass');    //return string T_STRING
isRW('abstract');           //return string T_ABSTRACT
isRW('self');               //return string T_STRING
isRW('array');              //return string T_ARRAY
isRW('is_array');           //return string T_STRING
isRW('callable');           //return string T_CALLABLE
isRW('isset');              //return string T_ISSET
isRW('and');                //return string T_LOGICAL_AND
isRW('echo');               //return string T_ECHO
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, checking for reserved words in php can be a bit more tricky than simply looking up the values in a list.

There are two things that should be taken into account:

- PHP version where you want to use the reserved word
- Where you want to use it - function/namespace/constant/class/method name

The same reserved word can have different behavior in your code depending on this, let's take the `array` keyword for example.

- It can't be used as a constant name from version 4.0 up to version 7.0, but can be used starting from 7.0
- It can't be used as  part of a namespace from version 4.0 up to version 8.0, but can be used starting from 8.0
- It can't be used as a class name starting from version 4.0
- It can't be used as a function name starting from version 4.0
- It can't be used as a method name from version 4.0 up to version 7.0, but can be used starting from 7.0

Another example, `namespace`

- It can't be used as a constant name from version 5.3 up to version 7.0, but can be used starting from 7.0
- It can't be used as  part of a namespace from version 5.3, and with `__halt_compiler` is one of the two exclusions that cannot be used in namespaces even in version 8.0
- It can't be used as a class name starting from version 5.3
- It can't be used as a function name starting from version 5.3
- It can't be used as a method name from version 5.3 up to version 7.0, but can be used starting from 7.0

As you see, there are many nuances, that depend on a lot of changes in different versions.

I had the same needs and created a library for that purpose. It can be used in complex use-cases to check whether a reserved word can be used in specific places for specific php versions.
Please take a look, maybe it can solve your problem.

https://github.com/sspat/reserved-words

Answer (score 0):

There's an accepted answer already, but i agree with @HoldOffHunger that performance is an issue with such a large list of values.

But rather than make a large number of edits to that answer to address issues, here's my version. It separates keywords that are case-insensitive and compares them against a lower-case version of the passed argument.

Credit to @HoldOffHunger for the initial structure.

```php
class PHPReservedWords {
    private $word_hash = [];

    public function isWordReserved(string $word) {
        $hashes = $this->reservedWordsHash();

        return isset($hashes['cs'][$word])
               || isset($hashes['ci'][strtolower($word)]);
    }

    public function reservedWordsHash() {
        if (!$this->word_hash) {
            $hash = $this->reservedWords();
            $this->word_hash['ci'] = array_change_key_case(array_flip($hash['ci']));
            $this->word_hash['cs'] = array_flip($hash['cs']);
        }

        return $this->word_hash;
    }
    public function reservedWords() {
        // Primary Source: https://php.net/manual/en/reserved.php
        // ------------------------------------------------------
        $keywords = [
            // https://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php
            // -----------------------------------------------
            'ci' => [
                '__halt_compiler', 'abstract', 'and', 'array', 'as',
                'break', 'callable', 'case', 'catch', 'class', 'clone',
                'const', 'continue', 'declare', 'default', 'die', 'do',
                'echo', 'else', 'elseif', 'empty', 'enddeclare', 'endfor',
                'endforeach', 'endif', 'endswitch', 'endwhile', 'eval',
                'exit', 'extends', 'final', 'finally', 'for', 'foreach',
                'function', 'global', 'goto', 'if', 'implements', 'include',
                'include_once', 'instanceof', 'insteadof', 'interface',
                'isset', 'list', 'namespace', 'new', 'or', 'print', 'private',
                'protected', 'public', 'require', 'require_once', 'return',
                'static', 'switch', 'throw', 'trait', 'try', 'unset', 'use',
                'var', 'while', 'xor', 'yield', 'yield from',

                // https://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php
                // ------------------------------------------------
                'true', 'false', 'null',

                // https://php.net/manual/en/reserved.other-reserved-words.php
                // -----------------------------------------------------------
                'int', 'float', 'bool', 'string', 'true', 'false',
                'null', 'resource', 'mixed', 'numeric',
            ],
            'cs' => [
                // https://php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php
                // ----------------------------------------------
                'Directory', 'stdClass', '__PHP_Incomplete_Class',
                'Exception', 'ErrorException', 'php_user_filter',
                'Closure', 'Generator', 'ArithmeticError',
                'AssertionError', 'DivisionByZeroError', 'Error',
                'Throwable', 'ParseError', 'TypeError',
                'self', 'static', 'parent',

                // https://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php
                // ------------------------------------------------
                'PHP_VERSION', 'PHP_MAJOR_VERSION', 'PHP_MINOR_VERSION',
                'PHP_RELEASE_VERSION', 'PHP_VERSION_ID', 'PHP_EXTRA_VERSION',
                'PHP_ZTS', 'PHP_DEBUG', 'PHP_MAXPATHLEN', 'PHP_OS',
                'PHP_OS_FAMILY', 'PHP_SAPI', 'PHP_EOL', 'PHP_INT_MAX',
                'PHP_INT_MIN', 'PHP_INT_SIZE', 'PHP_FLOAT_DIG',
                'PHP_FLOAT_EPSILON', 'PHP_FLOAT_MIN', 'PHP_FLOAT_MAX',
                'DEFAULT_INCLUDE_PATH', 'PEAR_INSTALL_DIR', 'PEAR_EXTENSION_DIR',
                'PHP_EXTENSION_DIR', 'PHP_PREFIX', 'PHP_BINDIR', 'PHP_BINARY',
                'PHP_MANDIR', 'PHP_LIBDIR', 'PHP_DATADIR', 'PHP_SYSCONFDIR',
                'PHP_LOCALSTATEDIR', 'PHP_CONFIG_FILE_PATH', 'PHP_CONFIG_FILE_SCAN_DIR',
                'PHP_SHLIB_SUFFIX', 'PHP_FD_SETSIZE', 'E_ERROR', 'E_WARNING',
                'E_PARSE', 'E_NOTICE', 'E_CORE_ERROR', 'E_CORE_WARNING',
                'E_COMPILE_ERROR', 'E_COMPILE_WARNING', 'E_USER_ERROR',
                'E_USER_WARNING', 'E_USER_NOTICE', 'E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR',
                'E_DEPRECATED', 'E_USER_DEPRECATED', 'E_ALL', 'E_STRICT',
                'PHP_WINDOWS_EVENT_CTRL_C', 'PHP_WINDOWS_EVENT_CTRL_BREAK',
            ],
        ];
        $version = explode('.', PHP_VERSION);
        /*
         * Starting at the highest matching version,
         * add keywords that came into play up to that point
         */
        switch ("{$version[0]}.{$version[1]}") {
            case '8.2':
            case '8.1':
                $keywords['ci'][] = 'readonly';
            case '8.0':
                $keywords['ci'][] = 'match';
            case '7.4':
                $keywords['ci'][] = 'fn';
            case '7.3':
            case '7.2':
                $keywords['ci'][] = 'object';
            case '7.1':
                array_push(
                    $keywords['ci'],
                    'void',
                    'iterable'
                );
            case '7.0':
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception('Your version of PHP is too old');
        }

        return $keywords;
    }
}
```

Working code: https://onlinephp.io/c/51226