# Is there a built-in PHP function to check if a given string is a reserved keyword?

Tags: php, reserved-words

I'm looking at this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.php
I've made numerous search queries for things like: "php determine if string is reserved keyword".

I find nothing, and I'm starting to seriously sweat. Please don't tell me I'm going to have to code a complicated script to regularly scrape the PHP manual for all these various kinds of reserved keywords and build my own database!

***Please*** let there be a nice, simple function to simply check:

```
var_dump(is_reserved_php_keyword('if'));
```

And it gives a true/false.

Comment: No, there isn't. But you can make your own function. Define an array of reserved keywords (take them from PHP documentation) and check if passed parameter is there. You can take care about PHP version inside that function, as there are some reserved keywords that depend on the PHP version it is used. https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.php

Comment: This might solve your problem Similar Question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21504716/how-can-i-check-whether-a-word-is-reserved-by-php)

Comment: This similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21504716/how-can-i-check-whether-a-word-is-reserved-by-php) might be helpful for you

Comment: What do you need the function for? The manual warns that documented list is neither exhaustive nor complete and reserved keywords have different effects in the language depending type and context (e.g. you can't use `String` as class name but it's allowed for a constant, problems aside). I'm sure the specific use case is a very important piece of info.

Comment: Duplicated.. i provided an answer to that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21504716/how-can-i-check-whether-a-word-is-reserved-by-php/66579893#66579893), go try it..

Answer (score 3):

I went a different way to Andrew and instead went for having PHP figure it out rather than hard coding the list.

```php
function isPhpKeyword($testString) {
    // First check it's actually a word and not an expression/number
    if (!preg_match('/^[a-z]+$/i', $testString)) {
        return false;
    }
    $tokenised = token_get_all('<?php ' . $testString . '; ?>');
    // tokenised[0] = opening PHP tag, tokenised[1] = our test string
    return reset($tokenised[1]) !== T_STRING;
}
```

https://3v4l.org/WA6dr

This has a few advantages:

1. It doesn't need the list to be maintained as PHP's own parser says what's valid or not.
2. It's a lot simpler to understand.

Comment: I guess there're several keyword categories. This function doesn't consider the [other reserved words](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.other-reserved-words.php) list, which includes stuff like `String` or `false`. That's why I think the exact purpose is fairly important.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález `false` isn't a keyword, it's a predefined constant. `String` is a reserved word, not a keyword. I don't mind updating the answer to indicate the distinctions here, but the question was asking about keywords and this detects keywords.

Comment: `false` is listed as "reserved word" regarding class, interface, trait and namespaces. The OP linked the manual section index and mentioned "all these various kinds of reserved keywords". This answer is very useful anyway, I just clarified what it provides exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any built-in function for what you describe. But based on the RegEx pattern you can find among the contributed notes on PHP.net, you can test it like this:

```
$reserved_pattern = "/\b((a(bstract|nd|rray|s))|(c(a(llable|se|tch)|l(ass|one)|on(st|tinue)))|(d(e(clare|fault)|ie|o))|(e(cho|lse(if)?|mpty|nd(declare|for(each)|if|switch|while)|val|x(it|tends)))|(f(inal|or(each)?|unction))|(g(lobal|oto))|(i(f|mplements|n(clude(_once)?|st(anceof|eadof)|terface)|sset))|(n(amespace|ew))|(p(r(i(nt|vate)|otected)|ublic))|(re(quire(_once)?|turn))|(s(tatic|witch))|(t(hrow|r(ait|y)))|(u(nset|se))|(__halt_compiler|break|list|(x)?or|var|while))\b/";

if(!preg_match($reserved_pattern, $myString)) {
    // It is not reserved!
};
```

It may not be the most elegant-looking piece of PHP code out there, but it gets the job done.

**UPDATE:** See online demo of function here: https://3v4l.org/CdIjt